# Samsung S23 Full HD

Tags: media-queries, samsung-mobile

I have a web page that has Ifram and by Samsung S23 the iframe do not get the right Resolution what media queries I need for Samsung S23 Full HD?

i tried Different Media Query,but no where I can find the right parameters for Samsung S23 Full HD.

Comment: "do not get the right Resolution" -- what specifically do you observe? Also, what makes you think media queries are the solution? Can you provide a [mcve] as is customary? Please, as a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Did you add the [viewport meta-tag](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/index.html#L11)?

Comment: Yes I have <meta name="viewport"  content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">